# Websockets with the ESP8266 using arduino uno board

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi, iot

I'm trying to make an iot device that connects to my wifi, establishes a socket connection with my golang backend and then starts to send sensor data from the ardunio.

I've got an ardunio uno board and this ESP8266:

[image]

I found [this websockets library](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets) but I don't know if I can import the .h files if I have "arduino uno" selected in the IDE

**My question:**
Is it possible to establish a WebSocket connection with my go backend using the esp model that I have? If so, how can I import the required libraries in the arduno IDE? I would be happy if you could give me some directions.

Comment: can you communicate with the AT firmware on the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library you linked is not for Uno with esp8266 module.

It is possible to use the ESP-01 with Uno for WebSockets client for example with ArduinoHttpClient library over the WiFiEsp library.

Better option is to use only an esp8266 development board programmed with Arduino IDE without the Uno.